# Am I interpreting my data incorrectly or have I done the test analysis wrong?

Tags: r, statistics, correlation, scatter-plot

I'm having an issue with interpreting my results and I don't know if I have done the test analysis correctly.

To me is seem like the test analysis data doesn't match up to verify the results of my graph.

For example I have done a correlation analysis for my data on C02 emissions for each States in Australia over time and came out with these correlation results below because I wanted to verify the trend over time between years of CO2 emissions.

```
1 ACT         -0.688 
2 NSW         -0.984 
3 NT          -0.523 
4 QLD         -0.931 
5 SA          -0.770 
6 TAS         -0.924 
7 VIC         -0.947 
8 WA          -0.198
```

Then I created a scatterplot with trendlines to use my original data.

[image]

Now the issue is that for example the state NSW has a very strong negative correlation of -.984 but in my scatter plot with the trendlines for the state NSW, the trendline only shows a slight downward slope, which doesn't seem to back up what my correlation test is saying.

I was expecting my NSW state to have a strong downward slope of the trend line due to having such a strong negative correlation coefficient.

Edited: Here are my Co2 emissions data points that I created my scatterplot trendline for the State NSW,  23.7314908, 22.3342672, 20.7885171, 20.8843319, 20.5552300, 19.0952626, 18.7432773, 17.6887825, 17.1345322, 16.7092861.

I tried using the Spearmen test as that analysis is used for a nonlinear relationship between two variables in a dataset but it pretty much gave me similar values.

Would anyone be able to explain if I am doing something wrong here or if am I just interpreting it incorrectly, if so would you throw me a bone on how to interpret the data if it is correct?

Answer (score 0):

It is just a matter of scale of your x and y axis.
If you make it so that the distance between one unit in the x axis (years) and one unit in the y axis (Mt Co2) is the same, you will get a steeper slope.

Try to adjust the y scale of each plot to avoid all that empty space.

It would be helpful to have the data points for one of the city to answer better.

Comment: Okay! I'll edit my post to add the data points in my original dataset for NSW. Thankyou for the feedback, really helps a ton!

Comment: Looking at the data you showed, your correlation results are correct. It is just a matter of visualization scale. 
You can see in this example it gets much more obvious when you adjust the scale
https://i.ibb.co/zHYKhvZ/Figure-1.png

Answer (score 0):

Correlation and slope are different things. In your case, think of correlation as a measure of how close your points are to your orange line: the decrease in NSW year-on-year is small, but the size of the decrease is almost identical in each year. By contrast, in Tasmania the average year-on-year decrease is large, but it's not consistent - there was a bigger drop between 2011 and 2012 than there was between 2010 and 2011.

Comment: Oh that makes a lot of sense now, thank you so much!!